# How to work with WCF wsHttpBinding and SSL?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I need to develop a `WCF Hosted in a console app WebService`. 
I made it work using the `Mutual Certificate (service and client)` method using `SecurityMode.Message`. 
But now i need to change the Security Mode to `SecurityMode.Transport` and use the `wsHttpBinding` with SSL. I made this code to host the service but i cannot get the wsdl with the browser, or execute some  webmethod in `the console app` client.

```
static void Main()
{
    var httpsUri = new Uri("https://localhost:8089/HelloServer");
    var binding = new WSHttpBinding();

    binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

    var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfFederationServer.HelloWorld), httpsUri);
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WcfFederationServer.IHelloWorld), binding, "", httpsUri);
    var mex = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    mex.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(mex);

    // Open the service.
    host.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Listening on {0}...", httpsUri);
    Console.ReadLine();

    // Close the service.
    host.Close();
}
```

The service is up, but i cannot get nothing on the `https://localhost:8089/HelloServer`. 
On fiddler the get request via browser shows me this message:

```
fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to localhost failed. System.IO.IOException
```

What im missing here?
Thanks

EDIT:

The `Console Application Client Code`

```
 static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new HelloWorldHttps.HelloWorldClient();
            client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
                                            StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
                                            StoreName.TrustedPeople,
                                            X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                                            "www.client.com");

            Console.WriteLine(client.GetData());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Getting this error:

```
Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel
```

Comment: Have you configured an SSL certificate to work with your service? You may want to get some background on this, since getting started with WCF/SSL is far from trivial. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733043(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thanks! Your link worked for me and now i can access the wsld via https in the browser. But from my client console app i get this error: ´Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel´. Ill put the client code in the OP.

Comment: I wonder if you are using the certificate correctly. I doubt it is issued to "localhost:8089". If this is so, most probably the certificate is rejected because of domain incompatibilities. Could you try to call `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a,b,c,d) => true` on the client before you call the service?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I put it and it worked. But now i dont know if it is good or bad.

Comment: It allows you to skip verification of such certificate issues like wrong issue date or incompatible domain. Anyway, I am going to post this as an answer and expect you accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to the service, you need to map the certificate to the specific port as described here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791(v=vs.110).aspx

As for the client, you need to skip the verification of certificate properties like valid date, the domain by relaxing the certificate acceptance policy. An easiest way would be to accept any certiticate

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a,b,c,d) => true
```

You can finetune the acceptance callback according to the docs to best fit your needs.